# Trying to remove spaces before and after a string along with the string and replaced with a single space within a file

Tags: sed

I am attempting to remove strings from file1.txt as part of a bash script.

For example, the file contains:

```
@some_group1 = take.me bake.shake test.test push.pull
@some_group2 = test.test take.me bake.shake push.pull
@some_group3 = take.me bake.shake push.pull test.test
```

The output I desire is:

```
@some_group1 = take.me bake.shake push.pull
@some_group2 = take.me bake.shake push.pull
@some_group3 = take.me bake.shake push.pull
```

I have attempted using the sed command but have no luck getting it to work.

```
sed -i 's/\[?]\$username\[?]\/  /g' file1.txt
```

What would be the best way to accomplish this task?

Comment: `sed 's/ test.test//' /path/to/file`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`sed`** solution:

```
username="test.test"
sed "s/ *$username */ /" file
```

The output:

```
@some_group1 = take.me bake.shake push.pull
@some_group2 = take.me bake.shake push.pull
@some_group3 = take.me bake.shake push.pull
```

Answer (score 0):

To use single quotes and insert a variable name do like this:

```sh
sed 's/ '"$username"'//' file1.txt
```

It's not very pretty, but could be useful sometime. Regardless of using single quotes or double quotes directly, there's a sneaky underlying issue with the code. If the variable contains a '/', sed will treat it as part of the 's' command, which means there will be 4 slashes and you'll get a syntax error like:

```sh
sed: bla bla bla: unknown option to `s'   #good luck debugging that :)
```

To deal with this, I usually choose another syntax delimiter character, one that I know is least likely to appear in my variable. For example, the new command would become:

```sh
sed 's# '"$username"'##' file1.txt
```